# Laravel joins visible for everyone

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-4, roles

I want to make a forum in Laravel 4 (don't ask me why lol).

but, I want to get a RBAC system inside of it, so I can show user colors etc...

The problem is, it doesn't work very well..

What I got:

`ForumController`

```
public function thread($id)
{
    $thread = ForumThread::with('role')->find($id);
    if ($thread == null)
    {
        return Redirect::route('home')->with('fail', "That thread doesn't exist.");
    }
    $author = $thread->author()->first()->username;

    $role_id = $thread->author()->first()->role_id;

    $role_id2 = $thread->comments()->first()->author_id;

    $color = Role::where('id', '=', $role_id)->first()->role_colour;

    $color2 = User::where('user.id', '=', $role_id2)->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'user.role_id')->join('comments', 'comments.author_id', '=', 'user.id')->first()->role_colour;

    return View::make('forum.thread')->with('thread', $thread)->with('author', $author)->with('color', $color)->with('color2', $color2);
}
```

So I want to get the `$color2` to work.

Right now he just displays the first value of the first post.

So perhaps ID 4 is the first one to post a comment, it will take the role_id of the user with id 4.

But I want to get the color of every comment poster so it wil propperly display.

**`Database schemes:`**

`user:`
[image: user scheme]
`roles`
[image: Roles scheme]
`comments`
[image: Comments scheme]

Hope someone could help me :)

*edit*

my models:

```
<?php
class ForumThread extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'threads';

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ForumGroup');
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ForumCategory', 'category_id');
    }
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ForumComment', 'thread_id');
    }
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'author_id');
    }
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Role', 'id');
    }
}


<?php
class ForumComment extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'comments';

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ForumGroup');
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ForumCategory');
    }
    public function thread()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ForumThread');
    }
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Role', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up the foreign keys in the migrations and in the models?

Comment: Yes i think so. I don't realley wirj with the migrate function, I prefer creating my database manually. But still I use the correct sql database structures.

Comment: My models have belongsTo and hasMany etc... don't know if you mean that?

Comment: So a comment has an author that has a role that has a colour? You should specify an author() function on the comment i.e. belongsTo, an role() function on the author (User)  i.e. hasOne and query with Comment::where('x', 'y')->author()->role()->get(). You shouldn't need to use join.

Comment: Yes an comment has an author_id wicj must be linked to the user id. From the usertable it must take the role_id and then from te roles table it must take the role_colour value. And could you maybe write down your last comment in an answer? Because I don't understand it very well...

Comment: do var_dump(DB::getQueryLog()); and see what query is generating.

Comment: @GauravDave this is what is gives: http://laravel.io/bin/qQw8O there are of course other queries.

Comment: @RobinR Could you relate to any query you want to execute in way, you want, but it is not working, try changing the query logic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on your latest comment, and your model updates you should try something like

```
$author = $thread->author();
$comment = Comment::where('author_id', $author->id)->first(); 
$role = $author->role();
$color2 = $role->role_colour;
```

Comment: So I did now, I got an error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$id for the line `$comment = ForumComment::where('author_id', $author->id)->first();`

Comment: I made some edits so it works a bit more: http://laravel.io/bin/LkOex however I get an error now: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$role`. It shows me `$color2 = $role->role_colour;` marked.

Comment: @RobinR, it may be because you don't have the foreign keys specified in the database. At least I can only see your primary keys but not your foreign  keys. I find it easier to use migrations and create the database tables that way, otherwise it's a bit fiddly. So for example the author_id should in the comments table should be a direct reference to the id field in users table (not a manually created author_id field).

Comment: I can add them manually, what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: @RobinR your database schema and your laravel eloquent model needs to be aligned. So where you have a relationship defined in your Model classes, you have to have that relationship represented as a foreign key in your database. For example author_id should be a foreign key referencing the users table id column, and so on...